# Intuitions about probabilities relating to evolving a two-qubit state through a CNOT gate

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, probability

[image]

If the initial state of $|x_0\rangle = \alpha |0\rangle + \beta |1\rangle$ and $|x_1\rangle =|0\rangle$, and the final state at the barrier is $|10\rangle$ (in the form $|x_1x_0\rangle$), what would the state of this system be in the form $|00\rangle + |01\rangle + |10\rangle + |11\rangle$?

Since $x_0$ is the control qubit, it seems the CNOT gate only does something when $x_0$ is in the $|1\rangle$ state. Does this mean that $x_0$ would effectively be "copied" onto $x_1$? What would the state of this system be?

Comment: In which state do you initialize qubit $|x_1 \rangle$? The plain answer to your question is, if $|x_0 \rangle = |0 \rangle$ is your control qubit, the CNOT gate will not change the state of qubit $|x_1 \rangle$. Hence, if you start with state $|x_1 x_0 \rangle = |10 \rangle$, you will end up with the same state at the barrier.

Comment: Just for the nomenclature, it is normally an implicit rule to order qubits by ascending index number. This means that, in a circuit, we name the qubits from top to bottom. In you case, we say the state at the barrier is $|01\rangle$ in ordering $|x_0x_1\rangle$

Comment: So in order to get $|10>$ with my provided ordering, $x_0$ would need to have $\beta = 1$ and $\alpha = 0$, correct? What would the full two qubit state look like at the barrier (e.g. $|00> + |01> + |10> + |11>$)?

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align} CNOT |01\rangle &= CNOT \big( |0\rangle \otimes |1\rangle \big) \\
&=  \big( |0\rangle \langle 0| \otimes I + |1\rangle \langle 1| \otimes X \big) \big( |0 \rangle \otimes 1\rangle \big) \\
&= \big( |0\rangle \langle 0| \otimes I \big)|0\rangle\otimes|1\rangle  + |1\rangle \langle 1| \otimes X \big) |0 \rangle \otimes |1\rangle \\
&= \big(|0\rangle \langle0|\big)|0\rangle \otimes I|1\rangle  + \big(  |1\rangle \langle 1|  \big)|0 \rangle \otimes X|1\rangle\\
&= |0\rangle\otimes|1\rangle + \vec{0} = |01\rangle
\end{align}

So when the **controlled** qubit is in the state $|0\rangle$, the CNOT gate have no effect on the state.

Qiskit uses [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) so $|01\rangle$ here is essentially the same as your $|10\rangle$ (reading it backward). So the CNOT gate doesn't do anything to the state $|10\rangle$ since the **controlled** qubit is in the state $|0 \rangle$.

---

You end with the state $|10\rangle$ in the circuit above at the barrier because your control qubit is in the state $|0\rangle$ and your target qubit is in the state $|1\rangle$ before the CNOT gate. Thus the state stays the same as $|10\rangle$. Also note that the barrier has no physical meaning.

Comment: So how do I end up in state $|10>$ at the barrier? And what would the full state of the system be, e.g. $|00>+|01>+|10>+|11>$?

Comment: I updated my answer... If your state at the barrier is $|10\rangle$  then that means the state before the CNOT gate is $|10\rangle$ since CNOT gate has no effect on this state... because the controlled qubit is in the state $|0\rangle$. This means $|x_0 \rangle = |0\rangle$ and $x_1 = |1\rangle$ and so $|x_1 \rangle \otimes |x_0 \rangle  = |1 \rangle \otimes |0\rangle = |10\rangle$

Comment: I just realized I read the image wrong. $x_0$ is the control qubit, not $x_1$. So an initial value of $|0>$ on $x_1$ makes sense.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, I've updated the question to hopefully be more clear.